# RegEx to match list

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript RegEx to validate a user input that gets a string containing a list of numbers like `3 - 4 - 5`, or `3 / 4 / 5`, or `3 , 4 , 5`.

So far my regex is

```
function(string){
    var reg = /([0-9])([^\s]|[\s])([\-\,\/])/g;
    if(string.match(reg){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So far I can get `3 - 4 -` but not `5`, and if I omit the whitespace it does not match anything.

I want a regex that could get all of *n* numbers divided by those characters (`\ - ,`), and not match alphabetic or other special chars.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is n statically fixed ?

Comment: Can your number be decimal?

Comment: _n_ is from 1 to potentially infinite, but in fact 10 is the maximum I've encountered. The number is int, since is the number of a copy of a tape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
function check(string){
    return /^\s*\d+(\s*[\/,-]\s*\d+)*\s*$/.test(string);
}
```

Notes

- I removed the g flag, which is useless, and I used `test` instead of `match` because what you want is to *test* the string, not extract a match.
- I added `^` and `$` to ensure you check the whole string
- the `\s*` allow optional spaces
- to allow numbers to be several digits (that wasn't clear in your question), I changed `\d` to `\d+`

Comment: Both yours and @revo 's are not getting two digits numbers

Comment: @fra9001 That's why I wrote *"if a number can be several digits, change \d to \d+ in this regex."*. I edited as it seems to be your requirement.

Comment: sorry I didn't refreshed the page

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the end of the input string by a `$`:

```
^(?:(\d)\s[-,\/]\s)+\d$
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jL9wR1/2)**

**Explanations**:

```
^                   # Start of the line
    (?:             # Start a non-capturing group
        (\d)        # Capture any digits
        \s[-,\/]\s  # Followed by a space, [-,/] chars and another space
    )+              # One or more of the previous expression
    \d              # Any digit
$                   # End of line
```

Javascript part:

```
function test(string) {
    var reg = /^(?:(\d)\s[-,\/]\s)+\d$/gm;
    if(string.match(reg)) 
        return true; 
    return false;
}
```

Samples:

```
test('3 , 4 , 5') --> True
test('3 , 4 , 5 ,') --> False
test('3 - 4 - 5 ') --> False
test('3 - 4 - 5') --> True
```

**Note**: I modified your regex based on your current inputs and regex. So if you're going to check more than one digit in a sequence you need to replace `\d` with `\d+` every where in the regex. `+` means one or more times. So it would be:

```
^(?:(\d+)\s[-,\/]\s)+\d+$
```

and samples:

```
test('39 - 46 - 5') --> True
test('69 / 85 / 23 /') --> False
```

Answer (score 0):

`/([0-9])([\s])([-,/])([\s])([0-9])([\s])([-,/])([\s])([0-9])([-,/])?/g`

Although, here's a simpler version. It's made from your code.

`/\d\s[-,/]\s\d\s[-,/]\s\d[-,/]?/g`

1. `\d` matches digits
2. `?` means the preceding statement is optional.
3. I did away with your extra parenthesis

This should be simpler for you to understand. Use the site I've linked to for future RegExp. It's a lifesaver.

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com/3b1j2)

Answer (score -2):

You can trim the spaces and apply the below regex.

```
function(string){
    var reg = /([0-9]+)[-|,|\/]?/g;
    if(reg.match(string)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

([0-9]+) will match one or more digits split by either `-`, `,` or `/`.